# How to install ubuntu in VMware on a Windows 10 home version laptop with AMD A8 processor

Tags: windows-10, vmware, amd-processor

I have a windows 10 home vwersion laptop with AMD A8 processor. I want to install ubuntu in VMware but facing issue. I have tried tried multiple options wth the answers found from internet but nothing is working for me. I am getting the below error in VMware 
 [error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01Lew.png)

I have tried to look for the vitualisation option in the BIOS but the virtualisation option is not even present. Can someone please provide a solution.

Please find below Detais of my system 
[system details1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChFYK.png)
[system details2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyhCv.png)

Comment: Go to Start -> Settings, then type "Turn Windows Features on or off". A new window will pop up containing a list of features, one of them being "Hyper-V" which might be checked. Uncheck it and restart the machine.

Comment: I had already tried this option, before posting this question. I do not even have the Hyper-V option, hence check the BIOS, but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

Alright you're not too far off going straight into BIOS but we need more information to help you with that problem...

So to my knowledge your processor should support virtualization (as I believe most A series chips do) but if you can provide a version then we can confirm that you do have a virtualization enabled CPU

And the larger problem is likely going to be with your motherboard. If the setting isn't present in the BIOS that's dependant on your motherboard's firmware. If the motherboard doesn't support AMD-V you're stuck looking at custom BIOS or a new motherboard (both of which aren't favourable). There is a remote chance that by running a VM on the machine the BIOS will enable virtualization automatically, I've done this in the past by using virutalBox and opening the VM without virutalization enabled and then resetting. This caused my BIOS to turn on virtalization on the next boot. That was for an Atom on a Surface 3 (Don't ask I know it's not an 'Ideal' situation) though sooo like I said remote chance.

Sooooooo finally, for us to be able to fix your problem we need your motherboard model and your CPU model (you can provide CPU model with a screen cap of the CPU page of task manager). And make sure the BIOS on your motherboard is up to date with the firmware from the manufacturer.

**UPDATE**

Your processor supports it so says AMD but your BIOS doesn't and likely won't because Lenovo. Your only option is to run custom firmware for your BIOS which would be dangerous and may not even be available.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed reply. I tried with updating the latest BIOS but the virtualisation option remains disabled and not even present in BIOS. I have added the details of my system as screenshots in my question

Comment: it appears that your processor may not support it, I was looking for the amd page on the processor and found [this](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-B-and-G-Series-Notebooks/G50-45-Virtualization/td-p/1664345) on the lenovo forums. He appears to have given up on it seeing that the BIOS doesn't support virtualization.

This leaves us with one question, is the  processor AMD-V enabled? Which I confirmed it does; just about every 64-bit processor does.

So it's possible by loading custom firmware but, **CUSTOM FIRMWARE IS DANGEROUS AND COULD EASILY BRICK YOUR DEVICE** good luck